# Firebase Security: Permission Denied Until Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, security, firebase, angularfire

I have a single page app and when I click through to my report page firebase says `permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data`. However, if I refresh my page firebase grants me access.

**Here are my security rules**

```
{
"rules": {
    "signup": {
      ".read": false,

      "$id": {
        // you can add new data but not change old data
        ".write": "!data.exists()"
      }
    },
    "users": {
      ".read": false,

      "$uid" : {
        // you can add new data but not change old data
        ".write": "!data.exists()",
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    },
    "reports": {
      "$reportId": {
        ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('reportsToView').hasChild($reportId)",
        ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('reportsToEdit').hasChild($reportId)"
      }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It sounds like the problem comes from the way you authenticate or navigate. Can you provide the minimal code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the input @FrankvanPuffelen you helped me arrive at the answer.

Comment: One of the many reasons to make an mcve: by reducing your app, you often find the solution yourself. It's akin to rubber duck debugging. Thanks for sharing the answer! Don't forget to accept it once SO allows.

Answer (score 1):

I had two firebase refs `new Firebase("https://domain.firebaseio.com/")`. One was authenticated and the other was not. I was able to the solve the problem by just passing my single firebase reference.

Comment: Multiple Firebase refs would not matter here. Calling new Firebase(...) would still re-use the auth creds as long as you haven't fiddled with the context--if you don't know what that means you haven't. So you resolved this accidentally by changing the asynchronous order of events, not by passing the ref.